# How do you make a HTML.EditorFor textbox exist on multiple lines?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-deployment

I have a text area where users have to write a description. I was wondering how to set a text box so that it is on multiple lines, allowing the user to see what they are writing. What I am looking for is similar to the environment that I am writing this question in.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need a Textarea right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you need to add MultilineText as below:

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you code have just changed the EditorFor to TextAreaFor like Below

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```